# Avoid redirect to comment page if comment is invalid

Tags: 7, comments

I have configured comments to display in the node page, but if submit an invalid comment (e.g. without text in the comment field) I get redirected to the /comment/reply/ page. I would like to remain in the node page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this, by using [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) and then change the `$form['#action']` value to point to the current destination.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could write what code exactly and where I have to put this.

Comment: I would appreciate if you write what code exactly and where I have to put it to achieve the wanted results. thanks

Comment: Add this to your node template
 $content['comments']['comment_form']['#action'] = '';

or add this to your module

mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['#action'] = "";
}